# Enable Copy Paste for expansion-panels

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to use the [ExpansionPanel component](https://material-ui.com/components/expansion-panels/) from Material-UI, but I am trying to figure out how to enable selecting text on the ExpansionPanelSummary so that the user can Copy/Paste text within the summary.

Comment: What do you mean by "if I can enable Copy Paste"?

Comment: Text selection with mouse in order to copy text (Cmd C) (i can disable the propagation of the panel with onClick={(event => event.stopPropagation())} but I still can't select text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ExpansionPanelSummary` leverages [ButtonBase](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.9.5/packages/material-ui/src/ExpansionPanelSummary/ExpansionPanelSummary.js#L107) as its root component. This means it is treating the entire summary like a button to control the expand/collapse.

The CSS in `ButtonBase` [specifies `userSelect: 'none'`](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.9.5/packages/material-ui/src/ButtonBase/ButtonBase.js#L29) which disables selecting text in the element.

The example below shows one way of overriding this:

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import ExpansionPanel from "@material-ui/core/ExpansionPanel";
import ExpansionPanelSummary from "@material-ui/core/ExpansionPanelSummary";
import ExpansionPanelDetails from "@material-ui/core/ExpansionPanelDetails";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import ExpandMoreIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ExpandMore";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    width: "100%",
    "& .MuiExpansionPanelSummary-root": {
      userSelect: "auto"
    }
  },
  heading: {
    fontSize: theme.typography.pxToRem(15),
    fontWeight: theme.typography.fontWeightRegular
  }
}));

export default function SimpleExpansionPanel() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <ExpansionPanel>
        <ExpansionPanelSummary
          expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
          aria-controls="panel1a-content"
          id="panel1a-header"
        >
          <Typography className={classes.heading}>Expansion Panel 1</Typography>
        </ExpansionPanelSummary>
        <ExpansionPanelDetails>
          <Typography>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse
            malesuada lacus ex, sit amet blandit leo lobortis eget.
          </Typography>
        </ExpansionPanelDetails>
      </ExpansionPanel>
      <ExpansionPanel>
        <ExpansionPanelSummary
          expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
          aria-controls="panel2a-content"
          id="panel2a-header"
        >
          <Typography className={classes.heading}>Expansion Panel 2</Typography>
        </ExpansionPanelSummary>
        <ExpansionPanelDetails>
          <Typography>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse
            malesuada lacus ex, sit amet blandit leo lobortis eget.
          </Typography>
        </ExpansionPanelDetails>
      </ExpansionPanel>
      <ExpansionPanel disabled>
        <ExpansionPanelSummary
          expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
          aria-controls="panel3a-content"
          id="panel3a-header"
        >
          <Typography className={classes.heading}>
            Disabled Expansion Panel
          </Typography>
        </ExpansionPanelSummary>
      </ExpansionPanel>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Selectable ExpansionPanelSummary text]

Relevant documentation:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select

Comment: Thank you very much ! Didn't know about this css property !